# SDL - Using a std::vector with SDL_Texture does not work, Array works fine

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, sdl

Example:

```
class DefaultTexture
{
public:
    bool loadFromFile(std::string path);
    void render(int x, int y);
protected:
SDL_Texture* mTexture; 
};

main:(...)
DefaultTexture mCards[2];
DefaultTexture X;
X.loadFromFile("Data/basic_card.png");
DefaultTexture Y;
Y.loadFromFile("Data/basic_card.png");
mCards[0] = X;
mCards[1] = Y;
mCards[0].render();mCards[1].render();
```

That works fine(I can see both pictures) If I use std::vector instead I can only see the first one.

```
std::vector<DefaultTexture> mGG;
DefaultTexture X;
X.loadFromFile("Data/basic_card.png");
DefaultTexture Y;
Y.loadFromFile("Data/basic_card.png");
mGG.push_back(X); mGG.push_back(Y);
mGG[0].render(); mGG[1].render();
```

Can anyone explain to me why its not working? (Not matter if I use 2 or 100, I can only see the first one)

Comment: Is it a typo that one of your calls to render has parens, and the other does not?  ( mGG[0].render; mGG[1].render(); )

Comment: Yes,I just forgot to write it down here.

Comment: Using a debugger, can you verify if the data is correctly pushed in the vector? It might be a case of a misbehaving copy constructor. Also, is this the actual code? From the looks of it, the bug might be something different.

Comment: Apparently not. First: 0x07e507e0 {mTexture = 0x0344acb8 {...} mWidth = 175 mHeight = 257 ...} LAST:
0x07e50808 {mTexture = 0xfdfdfdfd {...} mWidth = 0 mHeight = -1896279066 ...}||| The last one has strange Width/Height values(last one should be the secone one since I only have two?

Comment: So, its also working if I load the texture afterwards 'mGG.push_back(X); mGG[0].loadFromFile(path);' I dont understand why, but Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one uses = operator. The second one uses copy-constructor.

A possible solution is avoid the copy. You could use pointers :)

```
#include <memory>

//...

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DefaultTexture>> mGG;

std::shared_ptr<DefaultTexture> X(new DefaultTexture);
std::shared_ptr<DefaultTexture> Y(new DefaultTexture);
X->loadFromFile("Data/basic_card.png");
Y->loadFromFile("Data/basic_card.png");

mGG.push_back(X);
mGG.push_back(Y);
```

[shared_ptr reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: Thanks! That works. (Still hoping for a solution without pointers )

Comment: @AutobahnPolizei Look at the **rule of three** in that case. For your `DefaultTexture` class you need to provide a destructor, copy constructor, and copy assignment constructor.